# Document special macro with doxygen

Tags: macros, doxygen

I want to document a macro like

```
HELPS(enumName, uint8_t, element1 = 4, element2, last);
```

with Doxygen and convert it with the preprocessor to

```
enum class enumName
{
   element1 = 4,
   element2,
   last
};
```

to get a common enum documentation.
I used already the PREDEFINED tag in doxygen with

```
HELPS(param1,param2,...)="enum class param1 { __VA_ARGS__ }"
```

but this won't work.
Doxygen version is 1.9.1
Language is C++.

I usually document enum classes like

```
/**
 *  @enum enumName
 *  @brief a enum test class
 *  @var enumName::element1
 *  It is 4
 *  @var enumName::element2
 *  It is 5
 *  @var enumName::last
 *  It is 6
 */
enum class enumName
{
    element1 = 4,
    element2,
    last
};
```

which works pretty well.
For some reasons I am now forced to use a Macro (HELPS) and not a enum. The behaviour is the same and the documentation shoulb be as well.

I wrote:

```
/**
 *  @enum enumName2
 *  @brief a enum test class
 *  @var enumName2::element10
 *  It is 40
 *  @var enumName2::element20
 *  It is 41
 *  @var enumName2::last
 *  It is 42
 */
HELPS(enumName2, uint8_t, element10 = 40, element20, last);
```

which should expand in the doxygen preprocessor to the good working example aboth but sadly (with -d Preprocessor) it expands to:

```
/**
 *  @enum enumName2
 *  @brief a enum test class
 *  @var enumName2::element10
 *  It is 40
 *  @var enumName2::element20
 *  It is 41
 *  @var enumName2::last
 *  It is 42
 */
 element10 = 40   class   enumName2   { __VA_ARGS__ } element20, last);
```

which results in a bad documentation.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Which preprocessor, doxygen or compiler? Can you please make a bit more complete example? Did you set `MACRO_EXPANSION=YES` ?

Comment: I edit the question.

Comment: I see the same problems. `__VA_ARGS__` is always difficult and the question would be how represent it especially the the comma in it. When using a fixed number of arguments everything works OK. Maybe best to create an enhancement issue in the doxygen issue tracker.

Comment: I will do so tomorrow.
Thank a lot and keep on your good work.

Comment: Created an issue [here](https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues/8542)